# What is a Mat-lab function for « If-in »?

Tags: matlab, numeric, division

Problem statement: Provide a function that does the following: c1) two vectors D1 and D2 have 7 elements each, then form the division between the corresponding components of each vector and assign the result to a vector name D3, placing a statement that avoids division by zero (i.e., does not divide if element to denominator is null);

The idea of the problem, is to set an error message whenever one of the elements of vector D2 is equal to 0.

My attempt:

```
D1 = [d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7]
D2= [d21 d22 d23 d24 d25 d26 d27]
for i= 1:length(D1)
if 0 in D2
fprintf(‘error: division by 0/n’)
else
D3=D1./D2 
end
```

I don’t know if the “if-in” structure exists in Matlab. If it doesn’t, what could be an equivalent?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you may use [`ismember`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html): `if ismember(0,D2)`. Check also [`ismemebertol`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) if you want to detect numbers very close to zero.

Comment: You're looping over the indices. You want to use the loop variable to index into your arrays: `if D2(i)==0`, `D3(i)=D1(i)/D2(i)`, etc. Otherwise, remove the loop and do `if any(D2==0)`. Please take a look at the documentation page for `any`, make sure you understand what is going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid any division by zero is to modify `D2` by replacing any `0` with `nan`. Divisions by `nan` produce `nan`, so it's easy to tell which division would have caused a problem by simply inspecting the resulting vector `D3`. Moreover, almost all `Matlab`'s functions are able to handle `nan`s nicely (i.e. without crashing) or can be instructed to do so by setting some option.

What I've just described can be accomplished by using logical indexing, as follows:

```
% Definition of D1 and D2
D1 = [d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7]
D2 = [d21 d22 d23 d24 d25 d26 d27]

% Replace 0s with NaNs
D2(D2==0) = nan;

% Perform the divisions at once
D3 = D1./D2 ;
```

For more details on logical indexing, look at the relevant section [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

As the OP requests a function that does the job, here's a possible implementation:

```
function D3 = vector_divide(D1, D2)
   % Verify that vectors are numeric
   % and have the same dimensions
   if isnumeric(D1) & isnumeric(D2) &...
      (size(D1,1) == size(D2,1)) &...
      (size(D1,2) == size(D2,2))

      % replace 0s with NaNs
      D2(D2==0) = nan;

      % Perform the divisions at once
      D3 = D1./D2 ;
   else
      disp('D1 and D2 should both be numeric and have the same size!');
      D3 = [];
end
```

Error handling in case of non-numeric arrays or size mismatch might vary depending on project requirements, if any. For instance, I could have used `error` (instead of `disp`) to display a message and terminate the program.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help!! I’m really grateful!!

I created this function: https://pastebin.com/5S36YQWA

Comment: If you've found my answer useful in any way, please consider accepting it or upvoting it. Cheers!